# Click Event not working IIS 7.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis-7.5

I have a classic asp website using IIS 7.5. I have created a .NET application inside of the classic asp website. I have noticed clicking a submit button doesn't fire an event. It works when I debug but that's it. I have enclosed some code below.

MASTER PAGE (This calls a classic asp page to check if the user is logged into the classic part of the website)

```
        #if !DEBUG
            if (Request.Cookies["sessionInfo"] != null)
            {
                HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies.Get("sessionInfo");
                bool temp;
                cookie.Name = "sessionInfo";

                if (bool.TryParse(cookie["PortalManagement"], out temp))
                {
                    Session["PortalManagement"] = bool.Parse(cookie["PortalManagement"]);
                    cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1);
                    Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
                    Logon();
                }
                else
                {
                    Response.Redirect(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PricingDesk"]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Redirect(String.Format("{0}loginSession.asp?cPage={1}", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PricingDesk"], Request.Url.AbsolutePath));
            }
        #endif
```

ASPX Page (just a button)

```
    <asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    </asp:Content>
    <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnClick" runat="server" Text="Click" OnClick="btnClick_Click" />
    </asp:Content>
```

Code Behind

```
 protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Response.Write("<script language=javascript>alert('ERROR');</script>");
 }
```

WEBCONFIG (of .NET site)

```
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Database" value="Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=40;Connect Timeout=40;Server=<serv>;uid=<username>;pwd=<pass>;database=<db>"/>
    <add key="PricingDesk" value="http://address/"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
    <customErrors mode="Off"></customErrors>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="home.aspx"/>
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

WEBCONFIG (classic or main website)

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <defaultDocument>
            <files>
                <remove value="default.aspx" />
                <remove value="iisstart.htm" />
                <remove value="index.html" />
                <remove value="index.htm" />
                <remove value="Default.asp" />
                <remove value="Default.htm" />
                <add value="Pricingdesk.asp" />
            </files>
        </defaultDocument>
        <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultPath="/errorPages/unknownerror.asp" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL">
            <remove statusCode="401" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="405" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="406" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="412" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="502" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="501" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
            <error statusCode="404" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errorPages/pagenotfound.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="412" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errorPages/pagenotfound.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="406" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errorPages/pagenotfound.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="405" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errorPages/pagenotfound.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="403" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errorPages/pagenotfound.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="401" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/errorPages/pagenotfound.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="500" path="/errorPages/unknownerror.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="500" subStatusCode="100" path="/errorPages/unknownerror.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="501" path="/errorPages/unknownerror.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
            <error statusCode="502" path="/errorPages/unknownerror.asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
        </httpErrors></system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <compilation batch="true" explicit="false" debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
        </compilation>
        <pages controlRenderingCompatibilityVersion="3.5" clientIDMode="AutoID" /></system.web>
</configuration>
```

I've been searching all day for an answer and I hope someone out there smarter than me can figure it out!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does the .NET application reside within its own application pool?

Comment: Yes, it is inside it's own app pool. I have it set to .NET 4.0 Integrated.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it wasn't an IIS issue. It was due to the fact that in my classic ASP page I was always directing back to the main page and I was losing my QueryString. This wasn't happening while I was debugging because of the '#if !DEBUG' statement.